# Unable load jar from my jar: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I have this jar:

```
/weekly/
  /database.class
  /report.class
/META-INF
  /MANIFEST.MF
```

The MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: weekly.report
Class-Path: /root/java
```

In this jar i used two external jar files, postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar, javax.mail.jar. I also put those into `/root/java`.

but when i run it use

```
java -jar weekly.jar
```

It shows those two jars class can't find

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.AddressException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

even i try to put those two jars to my $CLASSPATH

```
       /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/lib:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/lib
```

It also shows same error result. I can successfully run it in my Mac, but when i try to remove it to my server CentOS system ,it shows those NoclassDefFounderror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Finding a JAR file using a classpath is similar to finding a package
>   file in a classpath. The difference is that when you specify a path
>   for a JAR file, **you must include the name of the JAR file at the end
>   of the path**.

So you can try something like this:

```
java -classpath /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/lib/javax.mail.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/lib/postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar -jar weekly.jar
```

Another option is to put your jars into jre/lib/ext (but I don't think it's a good idea)

Comment: Thanks, you means run this first java -classpath /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/lib/javax.mail.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/lib/postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar -jar weekly.jar then it will load those jar files, then run java -jar weekly.jar ?

Comment: @Jesse Siu No, "-classpath" defines additional entries in your classpath for the current execution. You just need to run one command (with your paths to the jars)

Comment: I try the command but it still java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver seems the jdbc.jar not loaded yet?

Comment: @Jesse Siu Yes. Check the path to your jar in "-classpath" option + check that the class, which is not found, is in the jar

Comment: Thanks, I checked the classpath for jdbc.jar, it's right and I used it in my Mac it also works. but in the CentOS server it still shows java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

Comment: @Jesse Siu I can't find "postgresql-9.1-901" here:http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html Are you sure you're using the correct jar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64839/discussion-between-jesse-siu-and-multisync).